# Why is my Python code printing only even indices?

Tags: python

You can clearly what I mean from the codes and console output.

```py
file1 = open("texxt.txt", "r")

lines = file1.readlines()

all_names = []

for line in lines:
    all_names.append(line.strip())

print(all_names)

for name in all_names:
    print(all_names.index(name))
```

Console

```
> D:\Codes\Flutter\learningdart>python text.py
> ['19th Mile', '19th Mile', '1Password', '1Password', 'ActiveTrail', 'ActiveTrail','AdEspresso', 'AdEspresso']
>0
>0
>2
>2
>4
>4
>6
>6
```

In case you need the text file

```
19th Mile
19th Mile
1Password
1Password
ActiveTrail
ActiveTrail
AdEspresso
AdEspresso
```

Comment: `index` function returns the index of the first occurrence. Since you have duplicates, the index of the first one is returned for the duplicate.

Comment: What did you WANT this to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want all indices using range() and len():

```
for index in range(len(all_names)):
        print(index)
```

try this :

```
file1 = open("texxt.txt", "r")
lines = file1.readlines()
all_names = []
for line in lines:
    all_names.append(line.strip())
print(all_names)
for index in range(len(all_names)):
    print(index)
```

If you want name and indices both then:

```
for name in enumerate(all_names):
    print(name)
```

Comment: Using `name` as the loop variable for a loop over indexes is very misleading. If you're getting indexes, call them that. And for your last example, I'd use `enumerate` to both the index and the item from the list at the same time.

Answer (score -2):

You ask for index So the position of an element. You need to get the element using :

```
all_names[name]
```